# Observe Media Library changes in iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, mpmedialibrary

I would like to know if it is possible to observe Media Library changes in iOS.

I would like to be notified every time a user adds, remove or edit a Media Item (Song, Artist or Album item).

I have still not found a way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use notification `MPMediaLibraryDidChange` to observe the library changes. 
Be sure to call `beginGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications()` first.

For reference
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply \o/
Reading that doc I realized that, for my case, I could use the `lastModifiedDate` variable instead of "observing" for changes :D